# Compatible bitset with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am using gcc-4.4.5 which doesn't support pointer_traits (no way to change this) Porting to an older system

Does anyone know of a boost::interprocess compatible bitset, I was using

```
vector<bool, boost::interprocess::allocator<bool, segment_manager_t>>
```

with a C++11 compiler but this is not supported by C++03 as I get the error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_bvector.h:438: error: cannot convert 'boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<long unsigned int, long int, long unsigned int, 0u>' to 'std::_Bit_type*' in return
 make: *** [output/jobs/lnx64/release/dbapp_objects/sas/code/ced/dbapp/shmbloomfilter.o] Error 1
```

Alternatively, does anyone know how to work around this?
Cheers